# Timed out when using vagrant plugin install command on windows

Tags: windows, plugins, vagrant

I am trying to install some vagrant plugins so I can create my local VM.
Here is what I got after executing `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` command.

[image: Screentshot of the output]

I have also tried `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest --plugin-clean-sources --plugin-source https://rubygems.org` command but I'm still getting the same error.

[image]

I also tried to install the plugin by specifying the path to the downloaded GEM file: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/usage.html

I download the GEM file to `/home/downloads/vagrant-vbguest.gem` and then command `vagrant plugin install /home/downloads/vagrant-vbguest.gem` and still getting the same error.

What do you suggest as a solution guys?

Thank you,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. There was some restrictions in my network. I just switched to another network and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

first get the ipv4 address of rubygems.org with

```
ping rubygems.org
```

then try this:

```
vagrant plugin install <gem_plugin> --plugin-clean-sources --plugin-source https://<ip_address>
```

Comment: Same problem, timed out.

Answer (score 0):

While Using windows OS I have to faced same issue
Solved the cases doing following steps

1. Install Ruby via RubyInstaller: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
2. Used https://packagecloud.io/amontalban/vagrant-hostmanager/packages/anyfile/vagrant-hostmanager-1.8.5.gem link to download this vargrant-hostmanager
3. Execute `vagrant plugin install --plugin-clean-sources agrant-hostmanager-1.8.5`
   *should put this file inside of the vagrant directory

It will be work